# How to get string of x:Name property of component in Xamarin form?

Tags: xamarin

I am working on Xamarin PCL.
I am trying to get the string of x:Name of any component.
Here is an example:

```
XXX.xaml
<Picker x:Name="MyPicker"/>
...
XXX.xaml.cs
...
string str = this.MyPicker.???
...
```

I need to get a string has "MyPicker" itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn986596.aspx) operators from C# 6 to get the variable name as a `string`

eg:

`Console.WriteLien(nameof(this.MyPicker))` will print "MyPicker"